# touch screen issue lsinput - 3b+ XPT2046 5"

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

screen works fine.

I've tried the many different suggestions online and they all only solve part of the problem then cause further issues.

I've got to the point now where it's just the touch that needs to register as an event...

So i run lsinput:

```
bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
   phys    : "spi0.1/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS
```

and /dev/input has the following:

```
by-id  by-path  event0  event1  event2  mice  mouse0  mouse1  touchscreen
```

now i'm pretty sure it's just the event not calling on the right file... but i have no idea where to go next..

Comment: Also here is the log file:

Comment: What log file? Please edit your question and paste the it into it.